# How to tell the minimum point of a higher order function?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I was following an example in my Complex Analysis textbook where we are finding the number of zeroes of the function $f(z) = z^3-2z^2+4$ in the first quadrant. They begin by saying on the real axis that $f(x) = x^3-2x^2+4$ is real and greater than $2$. I feel like this is supposed to be really obvious but I genuinely don't understand how they know it is greater than $2$? Would someone mind explaining why this is please?

I was trying to apply it to $f(x) = x^9-x+1$ and couldn't figure out what this would be greater than on the real axis. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We have $f'(x)=3x^2-4x=(3x-4)x$. So the critical points are $0$ and $4/3$. Since
$$
f(0)=4,\ \ \ f(4/3)=\frac{64}{27}-\frac{32}{9}+4=\frac{64-96}{27}+4=4-\frac{32}{27}>2,
$$
and $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, we know that $f(x)>2$ for all $x \ge 0$. Or one could confirm that there is a minimum at $3/4$ by evaluating $f''$.